# Gitlab omnibus external url not working

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, subdomain, gitlab

This is my /etc/gitlab.rb file :

[image]

I've ran `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and `sudo gitlab-ctl restart`. Yet, when I go to http://gitlab.hop-child.com I get a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. However, http://hop-child.com brings me to GitLab...

What am I doing wrong? Restarting my whole server isn't really an option.

Comment: Did you setup the subdomain in your DNS?

Comment: I shouldn't have to. nginx should take care of routing

Comment: Nginx only handles routing once the requests reach the server. You still have to setup DNS that tells the internet that `gitlab.hop-child.com` points to your server. You usually configure DNS with your domain registrar.

Comment: Oh true. Thanks, I'll try that. But that doesn't explain why it still works when I simply put `hop-child.com`

Comment: Obviously you've setup a DNS record for your domain name, and you probably have one for `www` as well, but you also need to setup one for each other subdomain you intend to use.

Comment: @BrokenBinary What you say makes total sens. I'm remembering all that DNS and network stuff I use to know a long time ago. I'm sure when I do update the DNS settings it'll work just fine. You can post a simple answer and I'll vote it up if (although I have almost no doubt) it works. I'm just waiting on the credentials to the registrar account. Thanks a lot for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're receiving, `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`, is a DNS error. Couple that with the fact that GitLab works on the base domain, and I'd say that you probably forgot to setup the DNS record for your subdomain.

Comment: You're right. After registering the domain name through my registrar, everything is working.